# BeagleBone Black won't boot off SD card

Tags: debian, sd-card, beagleboneblack

I just got a BBB and am following the tutorial provided on setting it up. At this point, I'm not interested in writing any image to the eMMC; I just want to boot the board off an SD card.

So far, I've formatted an SD card and wrote an image (AM3358 Debian 10.3 2020-04-06 4GB SD IoT) to that SD card using BalenaEtcher. However, I can't seem to get the BBB to boot off the SD card. I'm following the instructions to hold down S2 and apply power, but the USR lights never go all on or all off-- they're constantly flashing, even after 1 or 2 hours.

I'm using a standard 1.8W USB adapter and the provided USB cord to power the BBB, but I've also tried using my PC as power. I've also tried using different SD cards and writing different images to those cards. Nothing so far has worked.

Any help on how to remedy this issue would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT 10 May 2021:

I hooked up the BBB with a USB-ttl connector and used my PC for power as opposed to a wall adapter; here's the output when I try to boot up the BBB with the SD card technique outlined on the BBB "Getting Started" page. Hopefully I did this right!

```
U-Boot SPL 2019.04-00002-g07d5700e21 (Mar 06 2020 - 11:24:55 -0600)
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
Some drivers were not found
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.
RTC 32KCLK Source: External.
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from EXT4... ** File not found /boot/uboot.env **

** Unable to read "/boot/uboot.env" from mmc0:1 **
Board: BeagleBone Black
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
BeagleBone Black:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x54:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x55:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x56:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x57:
Net:   eth0: MII MODE
cpsw, usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 0 seconds
board_name=[A335BNLT] ...
board_rev=[000C] ...
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
6589689 bytes read in 440 ms (14.3 MiB/s)
debug: [console=ttyO0,115200n8 bone_capemgr.uboot_capemgr_enabled=1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet] ...
debug: [bootz 0x82000000 0x88080000:648cf9 88000000] ...
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Ramdisk to 8f9b7000, end 8ffffcf9 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8f92b000, end 8f9b6fff ... OK
```

EDIT 11 May 2021:

I tried booting the BBB off the SD card again, but I connected the BBB to my router this time. I'm not sure if that would change anything, but I did end up getting a different set of code:

```
CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
Some drivers were not found
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.
RTC 32KCLK Source: External.
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from EXT4... ** File not found /boot/uboot.env **

** Unable to read "/boot/uboot.env" from mmc0:1 **
Board: BeagleBone Black
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Checking for: /boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
2062 bytes read in 29 ms (69.3 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from /boot/uEnv.txt
Checking if uname_r is set in /boot/uEnv.txt...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 1
Running uname_boot ...
loading /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.94-ti-r42 ...
10095592 bytes read in 658 ms (14.6 MiB/s)
debug: [enable_uboot_overlays=1] ...
debug: [enable_uboot_cape_universal=1] ...
debug: [uboot_base_dtb_univ=am335x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dtb] ...
uboot_overlays: [uboot_base_dtb=am335x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dtb] ...
uboot_overlays: Switching too: dtb=am335x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dtb ...
loading /boot/dtbs/4.19.94-ti-r42/am335x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dtb ...
uboot_overlays: loading /lib/firmware/BB-ADC-00A0.dtbo ...
867 bytes read in 133 ms (5.9 KiB/s)
uboot_overlays: loading /lib/firmware/BB-BONE-eMMC1-01-00A0.dtbo ...
uboot_overlays: loading /lib/firmware/BB-HDMI-TDA998x-00A0.dtbo ...
4915 bytes read in 202 ms (23.4 KiB/s)
uboot_overlays: loading /lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0.dtbo ...
3801 bytes read in 353 ms (9.8 KiB/s)
fff ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.002177] timer_probe: no matching timers found
[    0.195806] l4_wkup_cm:clk:0010:0: failed to disable
[    1.415861] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added

Debian GNU/Linux 10 beaglebone ttyS0

BeagleBoard.org Debian Buster IoT Image 2020-04-06

Support: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian

default username:password is [debian:temppwd]

beaglebone login:
```

Comment: A 1.8 W supply is cutting it awfully close. I would use something more serious (your PC-s USB port should do the trick); and a good quality USB cable. Anyway - have you connected a USB-UART adapter to the debug header, or at least a monitor/keyboard to your BBB to check what's going on? The description "USR lights constantly flashing" says nothing useful. They are expected to flash during normal operation to indicate heartbeat and CPU/HDD/... activity.

Comment: I have not. I'll get ahold of a USB-UART adapter and report back.

Comment: @Tarmo Just updated my post. I'm a bit late on the response here; school got brazy.

Comment: Ok. That's it, no more output from the beagle? It's the expected output from the bootloader (uboot) but next there should be the verbose startup logs from the Linux kernel.

Comment: I just edited my post again and tried the setup with the BBB again (holding s2, applying power, etc.). I noticed a line at the bottom says 
"BeagleBoard.org Debian Buster IoT Image 2020-04-06." does that mean I actually did end up installing the latest image correctly?

Comment: The last edit shows a successful boot, yes.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the help, kind sir.